# Getting Azure AD groups of authenticated user via Google Identity-Aware Proxy -> SAML -> Azure AD

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, saml, identity-aware-proxy

We have two clouds:

1. GCP for our apps
2. Azure for user management

I need to set up a role based auth in my GCP hosted app based on the user groups he is assigned to in the Azure Active Directory. So I need to get the AD groups somehow.

The standard setup via IAP and SAML will return me a user email via `x-goog-authenticated-user-email` header. This is not enough as I also need AD groups.

I have found some feature called [SAML attribute propagation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/saml-attribute-propagation) which sounds like an option but I am not sure. There is no configuration example for this case.

Has anyone ever did that?